# Is JWT Token Revocation worth it?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt

I previously asked a long question regarding the security of JWT tokens but I want to focus specifically on JWT token revocation here. I am using JWT as my primary authentication mechanism for authenticating mobile clients of a mobile application. My question is: Is it worth implementing token revocation? Currently, I am using a short lifetime for my tokens and I am relying on TLS to prevent tokens from being stolen by unauthorized users. I have not implemented token revocation. But basically this means that if a token is stolen somehow, there is no way to revoke it. What concerns me more is that when a user logs out of the application, the last token they were using still works if I can't revoke it. And it also means that I cannot place a limit on the number of tokens a user can request since I'm not keeping track of any tokens that are issued. I've seen many applications that just store all issued tokens in the database, allowing them to revoke and regulate tokens. But this just seems to defeat the purpose of using JWT. Is it worth adding such complexity or is my current system secure?

Thanks in advance. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm currently thinking about this, too. I haven't yet come up with a situation where it would be necessary to revoke a token that I don't know. If it's guaranteed that there will never be a need to revoke an unknown token, you can implement revocation using a blacklist. This reduces the storage and lookup overhead and keeps the advantages of using JWT, while still allowing tokens to be invalidated before their expiry date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether it's worth it is difficult for anyone here to assess. It depends on what you are protecting and what risks you're trying to mitigate.

You can use [reference tokens](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/) if you deem it necessary to be able to revoke the tokens. It does force the services consuming these tokens to talk to the authorization server which degrades scalability and introduces a single point of failure.

There are initiatives being developed to prevent token theft. Take a look at the [Token Binding Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/91/slides/slides-91-uta-2.pdf) and [Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636).

Comment: Thanks MvdD. I appreciate it. This is really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, just use the upvote buttons if an answer is helpful. And don't forget to mark one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider the possibility that someone can extract a token, regardless of how you've secured it. It exists on a device you have no control over.

Rather than pass along a token, why don't you negotiate a secret key with the client and your server? They can use that key to sign their requests to your server and you can keep track of those secrets -- even revoke them if someone signs out. This allows you to keep expirations on the signatures low, so even if they are captured they are only good for a couple minutes.

Comment: Thanks Travis. You're right. The client's account is fully compromised if someone gains access to the client's phone. I will look into your method.

Comment: "negotiate a secret key with the client and your server" is a pretty big hand wave.  How is a negotiated centrally stored secret key any different than a negotiated centrally stored JWT?

Comment: Negotiating security keys with a client is very hard to do correctly and easy to mess up. 99% of the time: If you need to implement your own security protocols you are asking the wrong question. Besides, each token would require access to the key for each user, which defeats the stateless nature of JWTs as a centralized store is required.